# ERROR: Syntax error at or near ","

Tags: postgresql

Please resolve this query

```
select
    to_char(date_trunc('day',create_time),'DD Month YYYY') as date,
    to_char(min(create_time),'HH24:mi') as login_time where login_status = 1,
    to_char(max(create_time),'HH24:mi') as login_out where login_status = 0
from 
    users.access_log
where
    user_id = 1010
group by
    user_id, actionlink_id, date_trunc('day', create_time)
```

getting an error at or near ","

Don't know how to write where condition in to_char function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `join` to bring the two login and logout rows together:

```
select
    to_char(date_trunc('day',create_time),'DD Month YYYY') as date,
    to_char(min(a.create_time),'HH24:mi') as login_time,
    to_char(max(b.create_time),'HH24:mi') as login_out
from users.access_log a
left join users.access_log b on b.user_id = a.user_id
   and b.login_status = 0
   and date_trunc('day', b.create_time) = date_trunc('day', a.create_time)
   and b.actionlink_id = a.actionlink_id
where a.user_id = 1010
and a.login_status = 1
group by a.user_id, a.actionlink_id, date_trunc('day', a.create_time)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a [CASE expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE), not a WHERE:

```
select
    to_char(date_trunc('day',create_time),'DD Month YYYY') as date,
    case when login_status = 1 then to_char(min(create_time),'HH24:mi') end as login_time,
    case when login_status = 0 then to_char(max(create_time),'HH24:mi') end as login_out
from 
    users.access_log
where
    user_id = 1010
group by
    user_id, actionlink_id, date_trunc('day', create_time)
```

Comment: Actually, this is working fine, but I want login and logout time should be in the same row with respect to date. please, can you resolve it once again?

Comment: @PrabhudevVatnal: that is called [pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+pivot) or [crosstab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+crosstab) please have a look at the many existing answers for that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name or just [join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47281854/256196)...